# finding in .csv file using python script tp create a new .csv file

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, bioinformatics, analysis

i have multiple row data in which the data contains in a paragraph manor and i want to select some specific word with respect to the 'extId' column and then create a new sheet based on that, for example here is the original sheet -:

[image]

and the search words are "binding","activation", based on that i want the output(Extid show show all data which is associated with that term) as -:

[image]

i also have used the following code but not getting the desired result-:

```
col_list = ['extId','Ontology.prefix','Ontology.postfix']
df=pd.read_csv("master file.csv", usecols = col_list)
df =df[df['extId'].isin(df.loc[df['Ontology.prefix'].isin(['binding','activation']), 'extId'])]
```

Comment: pls try this `df[df['extId'].isin(df.loc[df['Ontology.prefix'].str.contains('binding|activation'), 'extId'])]`

Comment: df[df['extId'].isin(df.loc[df['Ontology.prefix'].str.contains('binding|activation',na=False), 'extId'])]